# How do I access to a function member of a derived class using a base class pointer when there are multiple derived classes?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism

Suppose I have one base class `A` and three derived classes from `A` called class `x`, `y`, `z`. Now, class `x` has a function member `f` that I want to access to from a class `A` pointer through polymorphism.

I understand that I have to also define the corresponding virtual function in class `A`, otherwise, I would get an error something like `"class A has no member named f"`. However, if I define the virtual function in `A`, I also need to define `f` in `y` and `z`, otherwise, an error saying that `"y and z are of abstract class type"` are raised. But sometimes, `f` is like a characteristic function only related to class `x` and makes no sense to define in class `y` and `z`, although I can write it in `y` and `z` without giving any content.

My question is in above scenario, what should I do?

Comment: Redesign your class hierarchy such that code which wants to call `f` only gets references or pointers to `x`, not to `A`.

Comment: why not make f non-pure virtual and give default implementation from base class. and having f() only related to x and not in y and z is a hint  for bad inheritance

Comment: @LorenceHernandez I wonder why you think having *f() only related to x and not in y and z is a hint for bad inheritance*. Isn't it natural and common that a child class has some feature that its parent class doesn't have, neither other child classes have? thanks

Comment: @Nicholas i though your f() is declared in base class as pure virtual, it was just a misunderstanding i think?

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see, you've 3 options:

1. Redesign, because your objects aren't right.
2. Implement a base function that asserts and then throws
3. test the result of dynamic_cast<> - and then fail if it returns null.

Answer (score 1):

> However, if I define the virtual function in A, I also need to define f in y and z, otherwise, an error saying that "y and z are of abstract class type" are raised.

that's not correct. if you defined a virtual function in a base class A, then you should compile fine whether you override this function in your derived classes or not, unless you explicitly made this virtual function pure ..

if this base virtual function is not pure, it will be called by default for object y or z if you don't override it in those classes, which solves your problem.

Otherwise, I would avoid down-casting. If you have a problem with virtual functions because your drived classes have too many unique public interfaces, then it's not IS-A relationship and it's time to review your design. For example, for shared functionality, consider composition, rather than inheritance ...